# Why would a field be missing from the Rules data selector?

Tags: rules

I've added a couple of fields to the standard product bundle included with Commerce, like so:

[image]

I'm now trying to add a rule (*Data Comparison*) based on the "Special Offer Active" field, but for some reason it's missing from the data selector:

[image]

The other field I've added ("Special Price") shows up fine.

Anyone know why this might be happening? I've cleared caches a few times and run cron to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer in the [Commerce documentation](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/faq/rules-field-data-selection):

> This is due to the fact that Rules only knows about the default fields that we tell it should function in a manner similar to entity properties. In order to access additional fields, you have to do one of two things in your conditions:
>
> - Use the Entity has field condition to ensure the field you want to access exists on the variable you want to use it for, or
> - Use the Data comparison condition to check the type of the entity (i.e. product type) to gain access to every field on the entity.

Answer (score 3):

Using "Content is of type" condition to show all the available field. 
Besides, install [Conditional Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) to enable inline conditional clause.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may have the same problem, "Entity has field" didn't work for me but using the "Entity is of bundle" condition did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing that is a gotcha (of course) is if the field type does not match the type expected. For example, i was mapping fields from node to another entity type. I had a date field in the entity i was mapping to BUT in rules it was stating it had to be a field of type Text. So i tested and sure enough if i made a text field, then it showed after doing the 'entity is of type bundle'.

Answer (score 0):

i had some fields missing with the 'Entity is of bundle' condition but triggering the rule once (updating a node of given bundle in my case) let the field appear in the list.